# Checking if a Java object is of an array type in JNI

Tags: java, java-native-interface

Say I have a MyClass class in Java, is there a way to check in JNI that a `jobject` is a `MyClass[][]`?

My initial idea was to use `env->IsInstanceOf(myobj, myArrayClass)`, but calling `env->FindClass("[MyClass")` throws a `NoClassDefFoundError`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I know this question is old but...

To find a class of your array, use:

```
env->FindClass("[[Lmy/package/MyClass;")
```

Comment: Actually that's incorrect as well, it needs the `;` at the end as well (as in Rob's comment).

Answer (score 1):

A little rusty on JNI, but a couple of things:

Call `FindClass()` on your fully qualified classname, using a "/" as a separator instead of dots. So, for instance if your class is `"my.package.MyClass"`, you would call `env->FindClass("my/package/MyClass")`

Since you have a two-dimensional array of your object type, you need to call `env->GetObjectArrayElement()` twice; once to get a row and another time to get a distinct element. Then you can call `env->IsInstanceOf()` on that element. Make sure you look up the correct signatures for these JNI calls, I've left them as an exercise for the reader :)

Comment: The problem is that I don't know if the object I get is even an array, and the JNI spec doesn't even say what would happen if I try to call GetObjectArrayElement on an object that's not an array. I certainly can't rely on C++ to tell me that I can't convert jobject to jobjectArray.

Comment: You can call GetObjectClass() to get the class of the object. In your example above it would return "[LMyClass;" 
If the class is contained in a package, the name would be fully qualified with "/" instead of dots (i.e., "[Lmy/package/MyClass;")

Comment: Indeed, but I don't want to get the class, then get the name, then compare the strings on each call. I guess the best solution for my case would be to create an array in the first JNI call and cache its class so that I can do IsInstanceOf on it.